# PixiJS Update loop & delta

Tags: javascript, game-engine, pixi.js, game-loop

**When using [PixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/), I noticed that sprites that I move in a straight line at constant speed sometimes "jump" seemingly randomly - usually falling slightly behind their expected position. This is especially noticeable with fast-moving projectiles.**

I assume this may have to do with my `update` loop, and especially how I use Pixi's `delta`.

My way of adding my update loop to Pixi's `ticker`:

```js
pixiApp.ticker.add(update);
```

My update loop using Pixi's `delta`:

```js
update(delta) {
    entity.x += direction * speed * delta;
    animatedSprite.x = entity.x;
}
```

I assume what is happening is whenever `delta` drops, my entity moves a shorter distance that frame, leading to the "jumps" and "falling behind" I see in the entity's movement.

I have also read that - unlike other engines - in PixiJS, `delta` is not actually "the time elapsed since the last frame in ms", but rather something else that's not in ms and that I'm not sure I fully understand.

Is there a way around this? I read something about rolling your own update loop, and Pixi's ticker potentially only being meant for updating the sprite animations themselves, but not for movement and other gameplay mechanics in the way I do it here?

Comment: Hey Ben.  Looks like you're doing it right.  When do the "jumps" happen?  What happens, visually, when they do?

Comment: Well, let's say three bullets are launched at the same time and are moving in a straight line in parallel. Every now and then, one of them will fall behind the other two.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like an iteration bug in your code, rather than a PixiJS issue.  Regardless of what `delta` represents, if you're moving all the sprites by `delta * speed`, they should all move the same amount.  Is it possible you're looping over a collection that changes/reorders mid-loop?  For example, for z-order changes?